# Is it a good idea to use the user's username as a salt when hashing a password like hash(username_str + password_str)?

Tags: hash, salt

Should I use one secret string as salt for hashing or is it better to have each user its own salt for hashing?

Consider these three hashes:

```
hash("secretKey777" + password);
hash("secretKey777" + username + password);
hash(username + password);
```

Which one is the hardest to crack and the safest? I think it's best to use `hash("secretKey777" + username + password);` because for each user not only has "secretKey777" as a salt but also its own username. In case code that hashes the passwords leaks, there will be no attack on all the hashes at once - each has will have its own unique salt.

Comment: This would probably be a better fit on [security.se]

Comment: @MikeW Thanks, I just asked it there, too. Here are link: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/69421/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-the-users-username-as-a-salt-when-hashing-a-password-l

Answer (score -1):

In my understanding, salt has to be:

a) unique for each user (otherwise, leaking the salt will allow building a [rainbow table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) for your specific salt to decrypt passwords), so `hash("secretKey777" + password)` is not an option for me.
b) cryptographically random (I don't have an argument for this, it's just a feeling that this helps).

I would prefer

```
hash("secretKey777" + cryptographically_random_salt_string + password);
```